# "NHibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists" on access to child collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, union-subclass

Little explanation: I have coupon series and coupons linked to the series.
Some coupons may ne activated, and they are stored in the separate table.
Here are my *.hbm.xml* files:

```
<class name="AbstractCoupon" abstract="true">

<id name="Id">
  <generator class="assigned" />
</id>

<property name="Number" not-null="true">
  <column name="Number" length="40" unique-key="UNQ_CouponSeries_Number" index="IDX_CouponSeries_Number" />
</property>

<property name="IsDeleted" not-null="true"/>

<many-to-one name="Series"
             class="iikoNet.Domain.BO.Coupon.CouponSeries"
             column="SeriesId"
             cascade="none"
             lazy="false"
             fetch="join"
             not-null="true"
             unique-key="UNQ_CouponSeries_Number"
             index="IDX_CouponSeries_Number" />

<union-subclass name="Coupon" table="Coupon" />

<union-subclass name="CouponActivated" table="CouponActivated">
  <property name="WhenActivated" not-null="true" />
</union-subclass>
```

```
<class name="CouponSeries">

<id name="Id">
  <generator class="assigned" />
</id>

<property name="Name" not-null="true" />
<property name="WhenCreated" type="DateTime" not-null="true" />

<bag name="Coupons" inverse="true" cascade="none" lazy="true" generic="true">
  <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write" />
  <key column="SeriesId" />
  <one-to-many class="AbstractCoupon" />
</bag>
```

After deleting one of the coupon

```
public CouponActivated ActivateCoupon(ISession session, Coupon coupon, DateTimeOffset whenActivated)
        {
            Remove(session, coupon);
            var activatedCoupon = new CouponActivated(coupon, whenActivated);
            Add(session, activatedCoupon);
            return activatedCoupon;
        }
```

, I'm getting the list of coupons in the series (.First() is for simplicity).

```
var coupons = session.QueryOver<CouponSeries>()
                .Where(cs => cs.Organization == organization)
                .List()
                .First()
                .Coupons;
```

When I try to enumerate children collection *Coupons* of entity *CouponSeries*, I'm getting the mentioned exception with the full callstack like this :

```
NHibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists[myPrj.Domain.BO.Coupon.AbstractCoupon#85d31f2f-f282-11e5-afb6-50465db51863]
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.DefaultEntityNotFoundDelegate.HandleEntityNotFound(String entityName, Object id)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.Load(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.ProxyOrLoad(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.OnLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.InternalLoad(String entityName, Object id, Boolean eager, Boolean isNullable)
   at NHibernate.Type.EntityType.ResolveIdentifier(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Type.ManyToOneType.Assemble(Object oid, ISessionImplementor session, Object owner)
   at NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1.InitializeFromCache(ICollectionPersister persister, Object disassembled, Object owner)
   at NHibernate.Cache.Entry.CollectionCacheEntry.Assemble(IPersistentCollection collection, ICollectionPersister persister, Object owner)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.InitializeCollectionFromCache(Object id, ICollectionPersister persister, IPersistentCollection collection, ISessionImplementor source)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.OnInitializeCollection(InitializeCollectionEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.InitializeCollection(IPersistentCollection collection, Boolean writing)
   at NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.Initialize(Boolean writing)
   at NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.Read()
   at NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at myPrj.Converters.CouponSeriesConverter.ToDto(CouponSeries series) in e:\Projects\myPrj\dev\CardService\myPrj.Converters\CouponSeriesConverter.cs:line 14
   at myPrj.Service.Coupons.CouponService.<>c__DisplayClass2.<GetCoupons>b__1(CouponSeries c) in e:\Projects\myPrj\dev\CardService\myPrj.Service\Coupons\CouponService.cs:line 30
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at myPrj.Service.Coupons.CouponService.<>c__DisplayClass2.<GetCoupons>b__0(ISession session) in e:\Projects\myPrj\dev\CardService\myPrj.Service\Coupons\CouponService.cs:line 29
   at myPrj.Common.Hibernate.DAL.HibernateSessionManager.CallTransacted[TResult](Func`2 func, Boolean commit) in e:\Projects\myPrj\dev\CardService\myPrj.Common.Hibernate\DAL\HibernateSessionManager.cs:line 172
   at myPrj.Common.Hibernate.DAL.HibernateSessionManager.CallTransacted[TResult](Func`2 func) in e:\Projects\myPrj\dev\CardService\myPrj.Common.Hibernate\DAL\HibernateSessionManager.cs:line 133
   at myPrj.Service.Coupons.CouponService.GetCoupons(Guid organizationOrNetworkId) in e:\Projects\myPrj\dev\CardService\myPrj.Service\Coupons\CouponService.cs:line 26
   at SyncInvokeGetCoupons(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Does anyone know what's the matter?
I've tried setting *not-found="ignore"* to *many-to-one*, as they suggest in many topics, but that has nothing common to my situation.

Comment: Use NHProf to find the query that goes to the database, this will give you better idea what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to add new CouponActivated instead Coupon, using the **same Id**.

More honestly, I shouldn't have executed Remove() and Add() manually for the members of bag, but edit collection + execute Update() on parent entity.